# How to query with clauses on mongodb /PHP7?

Tags: php, mongodb

It's my first contact to mongodb, I'm coding PHP7 with MONGODB database and don't know hown to query.

My query is working on mongo:

```
db.points.find( 
    { coordenadas: 
        { $geoWithin: 
            { $centerSphere: 
                [ [ -23.010382,-43.476006 ] , 10 / 3963.2 ] 
             } 
         } 
    }
)
```

But I don't know how to coding it on PHP:
...

```
try {
    $mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
    $filter = [
```

THE QUESTION IS HERE!
HOW TO CODING THE MONGO'S FIND

```
    ];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);
$rows = $mongo->executeQuery(“points”, $query);
```

...

Answer (score 0):

PHP code for the above query will be something like this :

```
$condition = array(
                'coordenadas' => array(
                    '$geoWithin' => array(
                        '$centerSphere' =>  
                           array(array( -23.010382,-43.476006 ), 10 / 3963.2)
                    )
                )
             );
```

If your db name is "**my_db**" and collection name "**point_collection**"

```
$collection = $mongo->my_db->point_collection;
$result = $collection->find($query);
```

You can refer the documentation for [find()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php);